# HTML href link to servlet with variable as paramter

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to create a link to a servlet with a variable as a parameter. Long story short, it doesnt work. Can anyone help me?
The table works just fine but the `<td>` for the links in each row remains empty.

The table was created by a ResultSet which I converted to

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows
```

and set it as

```
request.setAttribute("result", rows);
```

It is supposed to be a link to a detailview of a tvshow. so the detailview.jsp depends on what tvshow is clicked. That's why I want to send it to a servlet.

```
<table border=3>
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Beschreibung</td>
    <td>FSK</td>
    <td>Link</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${result}" var="columns">
  <tr>
    <c:forEach items="${columns}" var="column">
      <td> <c:out value="${column.value}"></c:out> </td>
    </c:forEach>
    <td>
<%-- Here should be the link to a servlet with an parameter of the name, so I know what tvshow was clicked, so I can display its detailview properly. something like --%>
<a href="DetailAnsichtServlet?name=${columns[0].value}">Click</a>
<%-- but it doesnt work. --%>
      </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```